# Keyerror 83 and a value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Imported necessary modules

```
banking=pd.read_csv("bank.csv",index_col=0)
banking.dropna(axis=0,inplace=True)
banking.insert(17,'deposit_yes',0)
for i in range(0,len(banking['deposit']),1):
    if(banking['deposit'][i]=='yes'):
         banking ['deposit_yes'][i]==1
```

Error:
a value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a dataframe

Keyerror 83
Raise keyerror(key) from err

Data:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/18RGaTG1-ClLAnn3Gm1Rh5PuXLljWdond/view?usp=drivesdk

Can you figure out the mistake?
Thank you

Comment: check for the key `83` in `banking['deposit'][i]`, it could be that it is missing and therefore the error.

Comment: @Krishna Chaurasia there are no missing values

Comment: with `banking.dropna(axis=0,inplace=True)`, could it be that you drop some rows? without the data it is difficult to say what could be wrong, could you share it somewhere and share the link?

Comment: @Krishna Chaurasia I have attached the data

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Prayson W.Daniel I am trying to find the average age of the clients those who have subscribed to deposit.I am new to data analysis.Suggestions are welcome

Comment: Okay! I have answer it below

Comment: @Prayson W.Daniel Thank you

Comment: You should avoid for loop in Pandas :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting average age of customers with deposit:

```
import pandas as pd

URL = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/18RGaTG1-ClLAnn3Gm1Rh5PuXLljWdond/view?usp=drivesdk"

banking = pd.read_csv(f'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id={URL.split("/")[-2]}', index_col=0)

# this will give you the average age of all with deposit of yes

banking[banking['deposit']=='yes']['age'].mean()

# explaining step by step
# filter data to get only deposit is yes
banking[banking['deposit']=='yes']

# select the age column and get mean

banking[banking['deposit']=='yes']['age'].mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things.

First. You're iterating over-index in your loop, but accessing data with labels `banking['deposit'][i]`. `i` should be a label, not an index.

Second. Never(almost) iterate over rows because it's slow. Use built-in vectorized functionality, in your case to get new column `deposit_yes` you can apply the following code

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'deposit':['yes', 'no']})
df['deposit_yes'] = (df['deposit'] == 'yes').astype(int)
df
```

Result

```
deposit deposit_yes
0   yes 1
1   no  0
```